# 'Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher' after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, encryption, luks

I upgraded my system from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS and now it won't boot. I am using LUKS encryption - during the boot I now get this error:

`Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher`

After retrying a few times it drops me to a busybox (initramfs) prompt.

I am running 3.13.0-83-generic x86_64 kernel. I believe (though I'm not 100% certain) that this is the same version as before I upgraded to 16.04 as there are no other kernels listed in the grub menus.

I'm a bit stuck! How do I recover my system?

Comment: Are you sure about the kernel? AFAIK 16.04 has a 4.x kernel.

Comment: I've managed to update the kernel to a 4.x kernel using a live ubuntu CD. I'm now getting a different error: "Volume group system-vg not found" lvmetd is not active yet; using direct activatuing during sysinit.

Comment: See new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837922/volume-group-not-found-after-updating-to-16-04-1-lts

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

```
xts
aes-x86_64
```

Then regenerate the initramfs files

```
update-initramfs -c -k all
update-grub
```

If you want to debug your initramfs further, you can extract the contents by using the following command:

```
gzip -d < initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic | cpio --extract --verbose --make-directories --no-absolute-filenames
```