# Volume group not found after updating to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: lvm, luks

I updated from 14.04 to 16.04.1 LTS and now my LUKS volumes will not mount and the system will not boot. I'm not sure where to go from here...

[image: Errors]

I can use a live CD to get access to the filesystem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Updated from 14.04.5 to 16.04.1. Had 2 VGs. One of them is still there, the other one is gone. `vgdisplay`, `vgscan` etc don't find it...

Comment: Try looking here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1573982 .  I found a solution that worked for me.